# Connect to sql server

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(MYConnection.MYconnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from [User] where UserName=" + txtuser.Text + " and UserPass= " + txtpassword.Text + "", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            MsgBox("Welcome")
        End If
        con.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code from my login form.. whenever i run the program and enter my username and password this will happen :

[image]

This is MyConnection.vb that i use to connect to my database

```
Public Class MYConnection

    Public Shared MYconnectionString As String = "Server=CLAIRETUMLOS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Capstone;Integrated Security=True;"

End Class
```

here is my dbo.User table

[image]

Comment: You are missing ticks around the data. That kind of  thing wont happen using SQL Parameters. Your code also wont fail on names like `O'Brien`. And never store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `'` for string field, but i advise you to use Parameters  to avoid SQL injections, like this:

```
Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(MYConnection.MYconnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from [User] where UserName=@UserName and UserPass=@UserPass", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtuser.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPass", txtpassword.Text)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read Then
        MsgBox("Welcome")
    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```